# iPhone Plus devices showing weird banding effects?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm having issues with some image assets and custom drop shadow drawing with weird banding effect on iPhone Plus devices. Seen image below.

[image]

I'm suspecting this has to do with one of our views which is a custom `UIView` backed by `CAEAGLLayer` who has content scaling set to `self.contentScaleFactor = self.window.screen.nativeScale;`.

I have standard buttons and other views that are overlaid on this custom `UIView`. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: And you're using different images for the plus device and non-plus device right?

Comment: @slickdaddy we are using pdf and also on other views different png images. They all show the same issue. I think this issue isn't related to the image resources since some UIViews with drop shadows drawn by code are showing similar issues. See item 3 on the image.

Comment: But you have created separate icons for non-plus devices (in @2x scale factor) and plus devices (@3x scale factor) right or are you using the same actual image assets for both devices?

Comment: @slickdaddyI have created an image set that contains the 1x, 2x, and 3x images. This image set is used on all iOS devices.

Comment: Are you using any library to display the image?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh no library. Just doing the standard way. Again, this issue happening with views that have a solid background with drop shadow as seen on the image posted numbered 3.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand the issue correctly, but the image on the right looks like your icon bar has a border stroke that is not exactly on the border and rather inset by 1 pixel (or 1/3 of a point). If this is your issue, then you might have a rounding issue in the coordinates for the border stroke. It may be possible that the effect is not visible on 2x but only at 3x.

Comment: This is playable for all the pictures?

Comment: I had this problem too which I couldn't solve.

Comment: It looks like a beautiful app. Not a helpful comment, I know. All I can add is that Plsu devices gave me trouble in the past and often it was by having off pixels, either in a rounding calculation, or because we were not drawing at the correct time in the drawing cycle (and the values we got weren't correct). The first one was already mentioned above, and the second one created misaligned views, not your issue. So yeah, not a helpful comment ; just really like the icon design there